# Combining multiple columns to new column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with multiple columns describing a persons data each week and a column describing their reference week. I would like to create a new variable containing the value corresponding to their reference week.

Example data;

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | G | J | M | 3 |
| B | E | H | K | N | 2 |
| C | F | H | L | O | 5 |

Desired output;

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Week | want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | G | J | M | 3 | G |
| B | E | H | K | N | 2 | E |
| C | F | H | L | O | 5 | O |

So far, I have achived to extract the variable names corresponding to the reference week but I can't figure out how to insert the corresponding value into the "want" variable.

```
dfnames <- c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5") 
wantname <- dfnames[df$week]
```

Reproducible example data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(LETTERS[1:(3 * 5)], 3))
names(df) <- paste0("Col", 1:5)
df$Week <- c(3, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `get` the values from your target column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(want = get(paste0("Col", Week))) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5   Week want 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>
1 A     D     G     J     M         3 G    
2 B     E     H     K     N         2 E    
3 C     F     H     L     O         5 O
```

Or base R with `sapply` to iterate through rows and do basic index `[]`:

```r
df$want <- sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) df[x, paste0("Col", df$Week[x])])
df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Week want
1    A    D    G    J    M    3    G
2    B    E    H    K    N    2    E
3    C    F    H    L    O    5    O
```

Comment: In base R can also try: `df$want <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(paste0("Col", df$Week), names(df)))]`

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on [@benson23's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947687/3560695), here is a `data.table` solution.

```
library(magrittr)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, Want := sapply(Week, function(x)
    get(paste0("Col", x))),
   by = Week]
```

Result:

```
     Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5  Week   Want
   <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <num> <char>
1:      A      D      G      J      M     3      G
2:      B      E      H      K      N     2      E
3:      C      F      I      L      O     5      O
```